# Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'T'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working with typescript and I encountered an error `Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'T'`.

```
type Item = {
  name: string,
  body: string,
  imgOne: string,
  imgTwo: string,
}[]
```

```
// In a different file, this function is present
interface Props<T> {
    className?: string;
    items: T
    setItems: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>;
    children?: ReactNode
} 

export const Carousel = <T extends object>({className, items, setItems, children}: Props<T>) => {
  console.log(items.splice(0,2));

  return <div /> 
}
```

```
// I am calling this function in a 3rd file.
export const HomeCarousel: FC = () => {
    const {Root} = useStyles();
    const classes = useStylesClasses();

    const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([
        {
            name: "Naruto1",
            body: "Dive into the world of shinobi to witness one of the greatest tales",
            imgOne: "/two.svg",
            imgTwo: "/one.svg",
        },
        {
            name: "Naruto2",
            body: "Dive into the world of shinobi to witness one of the greatest tales",
            imgOne: "/two.svg",
            imgTwo: "/one.svg",
        },
        {
            name: "Naruto3",
            body: "Dive into the world of shinobi to witness one of the greatest tales",
            imgOne: "/two.svg",
            imgTwo: "/one.svg",
        },
    ]);

    
    return (
        <Root>
            <Carousel<Item[]> setItems={setItems} items={items}>
                {items.map((item, index)=> {
                    return <CarouselItem name={item.name}/>
                })}
            </Carousel>
        </Root>
    )
}
```

The splice function isn't working, now on one hand it makes sense since there is no splice in the type **Item** but shouldn't it work by default since it is an array?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing `T extends object` with `T extends Array<unknown>`.

This way you'll declare that `T` (in your case `items: T`) will always be some sort of array instead of a generic object. And hence TS will know that `T` will have `.splice()` method because it's "inherited" from `Array`.

**UPDATE**
If that's not an option - you'll have to check that `T` or `object` is actually an array. Like so:

```
if (Array.isArray(items)) {
  console.log(items.splice(0, 2));
} else {
  throw "Expected items to be an array"
}
```

Or, if you want to use `.splice()` on any object in the future without having to check for it, you can use this: `T extends { splice: Array<never>["splice"] }`. It'll ensure that all types of objects will require you to define your own implementation of `.splice()` method which is compatible with the `Array.splice()` method.

Comment: Is there no other way to do this? I wanted to keep a generic object in case the function got something else other than an array. A pipe `T extends object | Array<unknown>` might work but then I have to typecast it later since it is ambiguous.

Comment: @VanWilder "*I wanted to keep a generic object in case the function got something else other than an array.*" then you wouldn't be able to call `.splice()` on it. Why would you want to make sure it could be something other than an array but still treat it as an array?

Comment: @VanWilder it's possible, see updated answer

Comment: @Maxim, if I am using `T extends []`, it is saying **Type 'Item[]' does not satisfy the constraint '[]'**.

Comment: Right, use `T extends Array<unknown>` instead. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @VanWilder `[]` is the empty tuple. `unknown[]` is an array of anything.